# Is it possible to prevent Form Attacks with Basic Math Security in symfony 2.3?

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm looking for a solution to implement a basic math security question under Symfony 2.3.

I found an article here: [Prevent Form Attacks with Basic Math Security](http://www.lateralcode.com/basic-math-security/) where is explained a plain php solution.

How can be created a custom form field and a custom validation for "math security question" in Symfony?

I know captcha is a better solution but... these are project constraints.

Comment: If this is required for a school project you should take the time to actually learn the content

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do this. Also, technically speaking, a math challenge *is* a CAPTCHA - it's just not a typical letter-scramble-style CAPTCHA.

The "how" is a bit more complex, and perhaps too broad a topic for an SO post, but I can provide some helpful links

First, become familiar with creating custom form/field types

http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

Next, study an existing CAPTCHA implementation in Symfony2 - look at how values are generated, persisted across the session, and then validated

https://github.com/Gregwar/CaptchaBundle

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

I would advised to use 'genemu' bundle. But I needed a quick implementation of a basic 'security question' (not 100% solid) inside a FormType
It should use Contraint and Callback but I don't have time to refactor.

```php
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
  // Map -> question/answer
  $securityMap = array(
        'a' => array(
                'q' => '1+1=?',
                'a' => '2'
            ),
        'b' => array(
                'q' => 'Are you human?',
                'a' => 'yes'
            ),
        'c' => array(
                'q' => 'What is the color of an orange?',
                'a' => 'orange'
        )
    );

  ...
  // Post validation (should use Contraint)

  $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::POST_SUBMIT, function (FormEvent $event) use ($securityMap) {
        $form = $event->getForm();

        $question  = $form['sec_map']->getData();
        $answer = $securityMap[$question]['a'];

        if($form && $form['sec']->getData() !== $answer ){
            // This trigger a global form error and not an error on the field..
            $form->addError(new FormError('Bad Answer'));
        }
    });
  ...
  // Pick a question
  $rand_key = array_rand($securityMap);

  // Question (key) added in form and will be POST
  $builder->add('sec_map', 'hidden', array('data' => $rand_key, 'mapped' => false) );

  $builder->add('sec', 'text', array(
        'label' => 'Please answer: ' . $securityMap[$rand_key]['q'], 
        'mapped' => false
    ));
}
```